# how to delete multiple folders,desktop and start menu shortcut using vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript

I never did any vbscript before, so i don't know if my question is very easy one. Following is the flow of steps that has to be done :

Check if exist and delete a folder at c:\test1 if found and continue. If not found continue.
Check if exist and delete a folder at c:\programfiles\test2 if found and continue. If not found continue.
Check if a desktop shortcut and start menu shortcut exist and delete if found. If not exit.

I could delete 2 folders with the following code:

```
strPath1 = "C:\test1"
strPath1 = "C:\test1"
DeleteFolder strPath1
DeleteFolder strPath1
Function DeleteFolder(strFolderPath1)
Dim objFSO, objFolder
Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFolder strFolderPath, True
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

But i need to run one script to delete 2 folders in different paths, 2 shortcuts one in start menu and one on desktop.

I was experimenting with this code to delete the shortcut on my desktop:

```
Dim WSHShell, DesktopPath
   Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   DesktopPath = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
   on error resume next
   Icon = DesktopPath & "\sample.txt"
   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set A = fs.GetFile(Icon)
   A.Delete
   WScript.Quit
```

It works fine for txt file on desktop, but how do i delete a shortcut for an application from desktop as well as start menu.

Comment: A shortcut is a .lnk, use the same principle with the right extension.

Comment: @daniel :to remove from start menu ,should i put the extension .lnk or is it considered as a folder there?

Comment: The extension .lnk is valid for a windows shortcut regardless of the location. The start menu is no different and is basically specialized folders. The path is obtained via WSHShell.SpecialFolders("StartMenu") but I assume you knew that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strPath1 = "C:\test1"
strPath2 = "C:\test2"

DeleteFolder strPath1
DeleteFolder strPath2

DeleteShortcut

'-------------------------------------------------------
Sub DeleteFolder(strFolderPath)
  Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If fso.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
    fso.DeleteFolder strFolderPath, True
  End If
End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------------    
Sub DeleteShortcut()
  Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  DesktopPath = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

  shortcutPath = DesktopPath & "\MyShortcut.lnk"
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If fso.FileExists(shortcutPath) Then
    Set myFile = fso.GetFile(shortcutPath)
    myFile.Delete
  End If
End Sub
```